# malloc, free, and memmove inside a subfunction

Tags: c, malloc, free, memmove

I want to use a subfunction to copy a char array.  it is like this:

```
void NSV_String_Copy (char *Source, char *Destination)
{
    int len = strlen(Source);
    if (*Destination != NULL)
        free(Destination);
    Destination = malloc(len + 1);
    memmove(*Destination, Source, len);
    Destination[len] = '\0';             //null terminate
}
```

that way, I can call it from the main function and perform the operation this way:

```
char *MySource = "abcd";
char *MyDestination;

NSV_String_Copy (MySource, MyDestination);
```

However, it does not work as intended.  please help!

Comment: FWIW, that whitespace style is *highly* idiosyncratic, and thus very hard to read.  I've taken the liberty of editing to make it readable to the rest of the world...

Comment: Also, "it does not work as intended" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: I think you need pointers to pointers here (double-star) - at least for `Destination`.

Comment: it's interesting how you use `*Destination` only at two places.

Comment: You didn't initialize MyDestination to NULL.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, my actual code has the malloc initialization.  you picked that out right tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C passes arguments by value, which means that you can't change the caller's `MyDestination` using the function prototype in the question. Here are two ways to update the caller's copy of `MyDestination`.

**Option a) pass the address of `MyDestination`**

```
void NSV_String_Copy (char *Source, char **Destination)
{
    int len = strlen(Source);
    if (*Destination != NULL)
        free(*Destination);
    *Destination = malloc(len + 1);
    memmove(*Destination, Source, len);
    (*Destination)[len] = '\0';             //null terminate
}

int main( void )
{
    char *MySource = "abcd";
    char *MyDestination = NULL;

    NSV_String_Copy(MySource, &MyDestination);
    printf("%s\n", MyDestination);
}
```

**Option b) return `Destination` from the function, and assign it to `MyDestination`**

```
char *NSV_String_Copy (char *Source, char *Destination)
{
    if (Destination != NULL)
        free(Destination);

    int len = strlen(Source);
    Destination = malloc(len + 1);
    memmove(Destination, Source, len);
    Destination[len] = '\0';             //null terminate

    return Destination;
}

int main( void )
{
    char *MySource = "abcd";
    char *MyDestination = NULL;

    MyDestination = NSV_String_Copy(MySource, MyDestination);
    printf("%s\n", MyDestination);
}
```

Comment: thank you, sir.  you fixed my problem.  first time I have to deal with pointer to pointer.  mucho appreciado.