# Initializing a structure in c without the use of memory manipulation methods(malloc... and so on)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I am trying to initialize  a struct pointer without using malloc or any memory methods. In doing so, when I try to increase the size of the heap, I get a  **segmentation fault**. Now, I bet I am going about this wrong. I did not initialize all the fields when a assigning dataHeap(I left out an array of structs Node) .Is there a correct way of doing this below or be kindly to point me to a similar problem?

```
///node_heap.h///
8 #ifndef NODE_HEAP_H
9 #define NODE_HEAP_H
10 
11 #include <stdio.h>
12 #include <stdlib.h>
13 
15 #define NUL   '\0'
16 
18 #define NUM_BITS   8
19 
21 #define MAX_CODE   NUM_BITS + 1
22 
24 #define NSYMS      1 << NUM_BITS
25 
37 typedef struct Symbol_S {
39     size_t frequency;
40 
42     size_t bit;
43 
45     char symbol;
46 
48     char codeword[MAX_CODE];
49 } Symbol;
50 
60 typedef struct Node_S {
62     size_t frequency;
63 
65     size_t num_valid;
66 
68     Symbol syms[NSYMS];
69 
70 } Node;
71 
82 typedef struct Heap_S {
84     size_t capacity;
85 
87     size_t size;
88 
90     Node array[NSYMS];
91 } Heap;

 /////////
//Heap.c//
#include "node_heap.h"
Heap dataHeap;
void initialize_heap( Heap * heap){
dataHeap = (Heap){0,250}; //size_T size, size_T max_HeapSize, Node[255]
heap = &dataHeap;
}
increaseSize(*Heap heap){
heap->size++;
}

/////////// 
// Main.c//
///////////
#include "node_heap.h"
main(){
Heap* myHeap = NULL;
initialize_heap(myHeap);
increaseSize(myHeap);'
}
```

Comment: What's the implementation of Heap? Can you post the relevant parts, too?

Comment: Well this is all the source code that produces the error.

Comment: `void f(int i) {i = 42;} int main() {int x = 5; f(x); printf("%d", x); return 0;}` *prints 5, because f(x) does not modify x*. Same principle here - a call to `void f(Heap *h) {h = &dataHeap;}` does not modify its parameter.

Comment: But you have never defined Heap as a struct or similar. And there is no definition of size. This will never compile.

Comment: Then it is impossible to manipulate a pointer by passing it through a function?Also the structures are defined and work as they should else where.

Comment: [Potentially useful information about manipulating a pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618434/malloc-free-and-memmove-inside-a-subfunction/28618699#28618699)

Comment: @MooCow Posting a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) allows other people to experiment with the code, making it easier for them to answer your question. Which is to say that adding the structure definition would definitely increase your odds of getting an answer.

Comment: What language has this numbers in front? I remember MBasic had such strange stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I wanted to modify the value by passing it through the method initialize heap, I had to do something slightly different.

```
   Heap dataHeap;
   void initialize_heap( Heap *heap){
   heap->size = 0;
   heap->max_size = 255;



   }
   increaseSize(*Heap heap){
   heap->size++;
  }`
```

Then when I try to initialize the heap I simply
initialize it like so

```
Heap heap;
initialize_heap(&heap);
```

Comment: You actually are not using the global `dataHeap` at all in this case, so you could remove it

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a variable to a function, the function receives a copy of that variable. If you pass a value and change it the change isn't reflected outside of the function. To change a value of a pointer you can pass an address of a pointer and then change that pointer through that address.

```
void initialize_heap( Heap** heap)
{
    dataHeap = (Heap){0,250}; //size_T size, size_T max_HeapSize, Node[255]
    *heap = &dataHeap;
}

main()
{
    Heap* myHeap = NULL;
    initialize_heap(&myHeap);
    ...
}
```